# "0/2" IPv4 destination in "netstat -nr" command on Mac OS X to view host routing table

Tags: routing, mac-osx, mac, netstat, ip-routing

I'm using the command "netstat -nr" to view the host routing table on a Mac OS X system, and here's the output I'm getting:

```
Routing tables

Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags        Refs      Use   Netif Expire
0/2                192.168.1.1        UGSc          125      676     en0
default            172.16.0.1         UGSc           33       10     en0
10                 10.1.80.1          UGSc           11     2318   utun0
10.1.80/22         10.1.80.39         UGSc           20        0   utun0
10.1.80.39         10.1.80.39         UH              2        0   utun0
67.192.86.200/32   10.1.80.1          UGSc            0        0   utun0
67.192.86.201/32   10.1.80.1          UGSc            0        0   utun0
67.192.86.202/32   10.1.80.1          UGSc            0        0   utun0
67.192.86.203/32   10.1.80.1          UGSc            0        0   utun0
67.192.86.204/32   10.1.80.1          UGSc            0        0   utun0
67.192.86.207/32   10.1.80.1          UGSc            0        0   utun0
67.192.138.237/32  10.1.80.1          UGSc            0        0   utun0
67.192.138.238/32  10.1.80.1          UGSc            0        0   utun0
67.192.138.249/32  10.1.80.1          UGSc            0        0   utun0
67.192.138.250/32  10.1.80.1          UGSc            0        0   utun0
67.192.181.96/32   10.1.80.1          UGSc            0        0   utun0
127                127.0.0.1          UCS             0        0     lo0
127.0.0.1          127.0.0.1          UH              1     1720     lo0
169.254            link#4             UCS             0        0     en0
169.254            link#10            UCSI            1        0     en6
169.254.69.22/32   link#10            UCS             0        0     en6
172.16/24          link#4             UCS             2        0     en0
172.16             10.1.80.1          UGSc            0        0   utun0
172.16.0.1/32      link#4             UCS             1        0     en0
172.16.0.1         40:8b:7:69:7a:c0   UHLWIir        34       26     en0   1153
172.16.0.6         a4:8d:3b:70:d5:61  UHLWIi          1      295     en0    418
172.16.0.10/32     link#4             UCS             1        0     en0
172.16.0.10        ac:bc:32:cd:96:39  UHLWI           0        1     lo0
172.16.0.14        8:66:98:cf:86:2c   UHLWI           0        0     en0   1089
224.0.0/4          link#4             UmCS            1        0     en0
224.0.0/4          link#10            UmCSI           0        0     en6
224.0.0/4          link#11            UmCSI           0        0   utun0
224.0.0.251        1:0:5e:0:0:fb      UHmLWI          0        0     en0
255.255.255.255/32 link#4             UCS             0        0     en0
255.255.255.255/32 link#10            UCSI            0        0     en6
255.255.255.255/32 link#11            UCSI            0        0   utun0
```

Can anyone tell me what the "0/2" destination in the first line means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would assume it means route `0.0.0.1 - 63.255.255.254` via `192.168.1.1` on interface `en0`. That's what it would mean in the non-apple world. No idea WHY is would say or do that but those utun0 lines look weird too.

Comment: You're right - we had a typo on the OpenVPN routes that was causing the route to be installed after connecting to the VPN.